# Send files to phone thorough print

Tags: files, phone, sharing

does someone know how to set up the computer and the phone so that it become possible to print a file from a browser (computer), select the phone as printer and get the file stored on the phone?

Comment: *Why* do you want to use the print functionality to transfer files? It ain't made for that, and I don't think anyone has ever made what you suggest, because printing is... printing, not transferring files.

Comment: Connect your phone and Print to PDF to a location on the phone or use e.g. Syncthing.

Comment: "select the phone as printer " nope. that is not going to happen. You can howerer mount your phone and put the file onto that mount (and that mount can be your pictures folder). Have a look at "mtp" transfer (that name might differ on iPhone/Android/Huawei)